# Getting content from span tag in python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I just want to get the numbers in the content how can i do

`in`

```
 yorum5=yorum4.find("span",attrs={"itemprop":"ratingValue"})
 print(yorum5)
```

`out`

```
<span content="5" itemprop="ratingValue"></span>
<span content="5" itemprop="ratingValue"></span>
<span content="5" itemprop="ratingValue"></span>
<span content="5" itemprop="ratingValue"></span>
<span content="5" itemprop="ratingValue"></span>
<span content="5" itemprop="ratingValue"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are using find rather than find_all so whilst this should work, you won't find all the spans, just the first one:

```
yorum5=yorum4.find("span",attrs={"itemprop":"ratingValue"})
print(yorum5['content'])
```

If you want to find all the spans, which I assume you do, then do something like this instead which will return a list:

```
yorum5=yorum4.find_all("span",attrs={"itemprop":"ratingValue"})
```

Which you can then iterate through like this:

```
for span in yorum5:
    print(span['content'])
```